# How to bind a dropdownlist with a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, dropdown

I have two SP's, both doing different things but they are connected by the I.d's... how can i bind these so that the label changes with the dropdown selection?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Refreshdata(214, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddMinutes(-1));
                BindDropDownList();
                LabelCount(214, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddMinutes(-1));


            }
        }

        private void BindDropDownList()
        {
            BizManager mgr = new BizManager();

            DataView dv = mgr.GetItemSeriesMaster().DefaultView; //how to filter data
            dv.RowFilter = ProductQueryFilter;
            Dropdownlist1.DataSource = dv; //datasource == usp.getitemseriesmaster
            Dropdownlist1.DataTextField = "Description"; // the items to be displayed in the list items
            Dropdownlist1.DataValueField = "Id"; // the id of the items displayed
            Dropdownlist1.DataBind();

        }

        private string ProductQueryFilter
        {
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductQueryFilter"];
            } //returns itemseriesmaster 214 or 225 from web config key.
        }


        public void Refreshdata(int selectedProduct, DateTime shiftStart, DateTime shiftEnd)
        {
            BizManager biz = new BizManager();

            GridView1.DataSource = biz.GetPacktstatisticsForShift( //passing in the usp
                shiftStart
                , shiftEnd
                , selectedProduct).DefaultView; //passing in the parameters for the usp
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

        public void Dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //this fires after a DDL selection
        {
            DateTime shiftStart = DateTime.Today; //declaring the param at today - As below
            DateTime shiftEnd = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddMinutes(-1);
            int productId; //declaring product ID
            if (int.TryParse(Dropdownlist1.SelectedValue, out productId))
                Refreshdata(productId, shiftStart, shiftEnd);
        }

        public void LabelCount(int seriesMasterId, DateTime shiftStart, DateTime shiftEnd)
        {
            {

            }
```

So, i am really stuck here, my label is placed inside a form view as i only need one record that updates very regular. I know the bottom method is not a form view but i was hoping there maybe a work around without using the form view. But i do not see any way to do this even after hours of searching the internet.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change an element on the page based on the drop-down selection but without refreshing the page?

Comment: I have a dropdown that shows different data in the gridview based on the selection made in the dropdown, and the label needs to change to reflect the change of selection in the dropdown list.... both the dropdownlist and label have exactly the same parameters i.e 225 and 214...

Comment: @danielcarey: if you need to change the label when the dropdownlist is changed, do that from `Dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged`. I have really no idea what the actual problem is.

Comment: I believe the problem is coming from the is page postback part, becuase i am passing in a value there and after each postback (30 seconds) its refreshing back to the value that is input... but that is not how i would like it... after each refresh i need it to stay on the page that is selected... but i cant find a way around not putting a defualt value (214) into the refreshData method...